# Can tensorflowjs_converter work with Keras models made with functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to convert models made with `tf.keras` in Python to `tensorflow.js` format for use in `Node.js`. Here are my package versions:

```
tensorflowjs: 1.0.1
Keras: 2.2.4
tf-nightly-2.0-preview: 2.0.0.dev20190321 (from pip install tensorflowjs)
```

Here is my Sequential model also remade with the functional API:

```
# Sequential API
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(22050,))
model.add(layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax'))

# Functional API
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(22050,))
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputs)
logits = layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')(x)
```

When I convert the Sequential model to `tfjs_layers_model` using `tensorflowjs_converter`, it loads fine with `tensorflowjs`. When I do the same thing with the functional model, I get improperly formatted model config error:

```
Error: Improperly formatted model config for layer {"_callHook":null,"_addedWeightNames":[],"_stateful":false,"id":1,"activityRegularizer":null,"inputSpec":[{"minNDim":2}],"supportsMasking":true,"_trainableWeights":[],"_nonTrainableWeights":[],"_losses":[],"_updates":[],"_built":false,"inboundNodes":[],"outboundNodes":[],"name":"dense_38","trainable_":true,"updatable":true,"initialWeights":null,"_refCount":null,"fastWeightInitDuringBuild":true,"activation":{},"useBias":true,"kernel":null,"bias":null,"DEFAULT_KERNEL_INITIALIZER":"glorotNormal","DEFAULT_BIAS_INITIALIZER":"zeros","units":128,"kernelInitializer":{"scale":1,"mode":"fanAvg","distribution":"uniform","seed":null},"biasInitializer":{},"kernelConstraint":null,"biasConstraint":null,"kernelRegularizer":null,"biasRegularizer":null}: "input_26"
```

I also tried exporting as `tfjs_graph_model`, but `tensorflowjs_converter` didn't allow that. I would like the model to eventually have multiple outputs, which is why I'd like to use the functional API rather than Sequential.

Comment: This may be due to a breakage in serialization format that was recently fixed, but may not have made it to nightly yet.  Can you check if this works in the latest stable tf release (1.13.1) ?

Comment: I uninstalled `tf-nightly-2.0-preview` and installed `tensorflow 1.13.1` but would get  errors when importing `tensorflowjs`. I got `ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_to_constants'`